# Failed to exec start script - EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node 8.10 and downgrade to npm 4 because i have error message with npm 5.

```
*******************************************************************************
ERROR: npm 5 is not supported yet
```

---

Then I use the command to downgrade npm
    npm install -g npm@4.

So I create my projet

```
$>npm install -g create-react-native-app
$>create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
$>cd AwesomeProject
$>npm start
```

And then I have the following error message.

```
> AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start /private/var/root/AwesomeProject
> react-native-scripts start

09:42:16: Unable to start server
See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
  sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880
  sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-23T08_42_16_152Z-debug.log
```

I have a look to the logfile

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.6.1
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~prestart: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/private/var/root/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
10 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: CWD: /private/var/root/AwesomeProject
11 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-native-scripts start' ]
12 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
15 verbose pkgid AwesomeProject@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd /private/var/root/AwesomeProject
17 verbose Darwin 17.2.0
18 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 verbose node v8.10.0
20 verbose npm  v4.6.1
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Have you an idea?

Best regard.

Comment: Try run with sudo npm start

Comment: I try it and I have the same behaviors. I have realized all my action as root.

Answer (score 7):

Try these steps:

1. `npm install -g npm@latest` to update npm because it is sometimes buggy.
2. `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the existing modules.
3. `npm install` to re-install the project dependencies.

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  on windows you want rd /s /q "node_modules"

Comment: step 3 is actually the most crucial step.

Comment: 'rm' is a Linux/Unix command to delete one or more files and '-rf' sets the command to run the command recursively and forcefully. If you are getting an error it is probably because you are using windows. You can either remove the directory manually or try using 'rmdir'.